# Polymorphic casts with boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, polymorphism, smart-pointers

I'm familiar with boost's `polymorphic_cast` on normal pointers:

```
Base *base;

Derived *d = boost::polymorphic_cast<Derived>(base);
```

But, how to use it with `boost::shared_ptr` instead?

```
boost::shared_ptr<Base> base;

boost::shared_ptr<Derived> d = boost::?????(base);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `boost::static_pointer_cast` or `boost::dynamic_pointer_cast`, as analogues of the C++ casts `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast`:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Derived> d = boost::static_pointer_cast<Derived>(base);

// now "d" shares ownership with "base"
```

This just performs the respective cast on the underlying raw pointer.

(The same is true in the `std` namespace in the C++11 standard library and for the `std::tr1` name­space in the TR1 library for C++03.)

Comment: Thanks. There's no `boost::polymorphic_pointer_cast<>` ? I guess just use dynamic and write the assert explicitly....

Comment: @Roddy: Not to my knowledge. But you can always say something like `if (auto p = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(base)) { /* ... */ }` if you need to check for success.

Comment: What about the reverse?  I want common code to use shared_ptr<Base> and call it from Derived classes that have Derived shared_ptr<Derived> ...

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore: The opposite conversion is already implicitly enabled.

Comment: boost::polymorphic_pointer_cast/downcast (you're looking for the downcast) is in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/conversion/cast.htm (since 1.58.0 I believe)